PineScript TradingView / Exit Signal /
Good morning,
how could I configure tradingview so that just before entering the contrary operation, it closes the operation with a tp/sl. For example, I am in a long and it just gives a short signal, how could I set it so that just before opening the short, first close the long and just after opening the short? thank you so much.
To have an exit signal just before the new entry

You just need to call strategy.close() before your strategy.entry().
//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

longCondition = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.close("Short")
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

shortCondition = ta.crossunder(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.close("Long")
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)



Hello @vitruvius,

Hello @vitruvius, thanks for ur help. In tradingview it helps but in the exchange didnt. I received this msg from the excheange. Dear Trader,
Could not execute your BingX signal trading (name: LtcBingX) Reason: The order value is too low.                                                                                                                                         I think it is because the signals are sent instantly and there is no time to enter the operation with the whole account. Is there any way to solve this? could it be put as a condition to wait a little bit? Thanks in advanc

You can try to combine the alert messages together. Some exchanges allow that. With the same message, first write the part to close the position and then write the part to open a new position. Adding a time delay is not really possible unless you want to wait for one bar.

How can i do to combine alert messages? In other exchange with the opposite operation i was able to close and open positions, but not in this one. How can i solve this problem? I saw this link but i dont know how to apply, can you help me please? https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-implement-a-time-delay-between-orders
